# Why do my huns need houses in AOE II Conquers expansion

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

So [the Huns](http://ageofempires.wikia.com/wiki/Huns) in AOE II Conquers has the special benefit that they do not need any housing and as a penalty for that, start with 100 less wood.
So I a few minutes after starting a game, I found out that I needed to create more houses!

After some searching I [found out](http://ageofempires.wikia.com/wiki/Full_Tech_Tree) that the full tech tree disables all unique stuff, inclusive the benefits, for the selected civilization.

So I started a new game with full tech tree disabled. And I still needed to build houses.
The part I did not tell thus far is that this is a multiplayer game with a custom created map.

**Is it because of multiplayer mode that these benifits are not available?**

Comment: This should not be happening. Are you absolutely sure don't still have full tech tree on? What was the population limit set at? Did building houses actually give you extra pop cap?

Comment: Population cap was on 200, but I got the message when I wanted to create my 6th unit. Building a house did give me extra pop cap.

Comment: @Downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doh! I found the answer to my own question.

When creating a custom scenario there is a checkbox under 'Options' named "Full tech tree", it was enabled...

So, regardless of what I choose in the game options the full tech tree was enabled. Now I'm not even able to build houses :).

Comment: The full tech tree button. it disables team bonuses and allows you to research all non-unique techs in the game. Of course, meaning the only the unique units and building graphics/audio cues change between civs with this ticked